# Absolute positioned eleement by no positioned ancestor set itself by monitor no body

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

Absoloute positioned element (input) place in bottom of monitor no body.

If i add a relative position to body, input place in bottom of body!

**why?**

```
<body>

     <input type="button" value="click" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;" />

     <div style="height:500px;background-color:red;"></div>
     <div style="height:500px;background-color:blue;"></div>
     <div style="height:500px;background-color:green;"></div>
     <div style="height:500px;background-color:yellow;"></div>
     <div style="height:500px;background-color:pink;"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the child element positioned absolutely from its parent element we need to set this on the parent element itself

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Comment: "if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body"

Comment: Hey @AliMottaghiPour 

The default position is static for any html element if not specified explicitly.
`position: static;`

It not relative